# Accessing variables between javascript files

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a web app where an object **property** is creating upon clicking a button in the **inputs.html** page. However, **results.html** needs access to the created **property** to prompt the user to save it in firestore.

- I have already tried importing and exporting the variable but get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ).
- I have tried creating a **const variable property** in **inputs.html** that changes using my script but I cannot access it in **results.html**.
- I have also screated a script tag in **results.html** linking to the javascript file where **property** is created.

Here is **inputs.js** used to create **property** and imported in **inputs.html**.

```
//create a property and go to results page
document.getElementById("createProperty").addEventListener("click", ()=>{

    property= new Property( document.getElementById("address").value, ..., );

    window.location = "../Frontend/results.html";
});
  }
```

Here is the code in **results.js** that calls **property** and is in the **results.html** page.

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click",(e)=>{

    //example of a possible output
    console.log(property.address); 
});
```

I would like for the console to log **askprice**. However, the error received is: Uncaught ReferenceError: property is not defined.

I was wondering what are the methods I could use to access **property** between these javascrip files.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering what are the methods I could use to access property between these javascrip files.

You can't share any JavaScript state across page loads, that includes variables. The variable `property` **cannot** be persisted from one page to the next.

Instead, you need to push your data into some kind of persistent store, like `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`, or pass it to the next page via something like the query string, ie `results.html?property=askprice`.